# Flatness and locally freeness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

Let $X$, $S$ be integral quasi-projective schemes (over $\Bbb C$). Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X\times S$, flat on $S$. Suppose that $x\in X$, $s\in S$ are closed points, and ${\mathcal F}(s)={\mathcal F}_{\rvert X\times\{s\}}$. Suppose that ${\mathcal F}(s)_x$ is a free ${\mathcal O}_{X,x}$-module. Does this imply that ${\mathcal F}_{x,s}$ is a free ${\mathcal O}_{X\times S,(x,s)}$-module ?

Comment: This seems to be true for me because of Theorem 37.16.1 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039A Set $X$ and $Y$ in the theorem both equal to $X \times_k S$, set $S$ equal to $S$ and set $\mathcal{F}$ equal to $\mathcal{F}$. Set $x$ to $(x,s)$ and $y = (x,s)$ and $s = s$.

Comment: Since $(\mathcal{F}|_{X\times\{s\}})_x=\mathcal{F}_{x,s}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X\times S,(x,s)}}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X\times S,(x,s)}$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, this seems like a commutative algebra problem.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm thank you, this works